# How do I join 2 variables in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

I have $db and $DATE set in my bash script, then I need to join them like this:

> mysqldump --user=usr --password=pss --databases $db | gzip > /backups/sqlNew/**$db_$DATE**.sql.gz;

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. How do I properly join those 2 variables into a filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `_` is a valid character in a variable name you have to separate it from `db`.  This can be done any number of ways.

- `"${db}_$DATE"` is one.
- `"$db"_"$DATE"` would be another one.

Always remember to [*quote your variables*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target) when writing bash scripts.

Comment: I would use "${db}_${DATE}" to avoid any variable substitution issues.

Comment: What issues do you mean?

Comment: For example, $DATE_OLD vs. ${DATE}_OLD  You are probably OK here, but just something to be aware of for other scripts.

Comment: Ok that's what you meant -- since the original question had a `.` after `DATE` I left that out since the focus was on the `db_` part.